# Change view of edge in Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am currently developing application with graph using Cytoscape.js library and I need to have three different types of edge view(like line, curve, polygon or something like that).
 Is it possible to create this using Cytoscape.js?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several types of edges supported (e.g. straight, bezier curve, segments).  See the edge visual style properties: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-line